# UPDATE Column in Same Table after INSERT using trigger in Oracle

Tags: oracle

i need to update one column in the same table after inserting is done. INSERT already coded and cannot be changed . So we are going with TRIGGER approach to update one column value.

```
create or replace TRIGGER "BLT_TRIGGER" 
AFTER INSERT ON BLT_MAPPING 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE BLT_MAPPING 
SET FIELD_ID = (SELECT CASE WHEN CORR_TI = 'B' THEN '12345' ELSE '54321' END 
AS INSTITUTION FROM BROKER CO,LOAN LO
WHERE LO.CORR_ID = CO.CORR_ID AND LO.LOAN_ID = loanid_in_BLT_MAPPING_table 
whcih_got_inserted )
END;
```

I am getting purge error . What is the mistake i am doing in thins trigger .

Comment: Please show your error

Comment: INSERT cannot be changed? Why not?

Comment: Why not contemplate having a MERGE whereby INSERT and UPDATE are possible with WHERE conditions in a single statement; thus, there is a possibility of correcting the records. Besides, as rightly pointed out by @eaolson, triggers are obscure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to update the same row that you just inserted? In that case, you want to make this a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, and change `:NEW.fieldid` before it is inserted into the table. Something like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "BLT_TRIGGER" 
BEFORE INSERT ON BLT_MAPPING 
FOR EACH ROW
    l_new_fieldid     number; -- Or whatever the correct datatype is
BEGIN

    SELECT CASE WHEN CORR_TI = 'B' THEN '12345' ELSE '54321' END 
      INTO l_new_fieldid
      FROM BROKER CO,LOAN LO
     WHERE LO.CORR_ID = CO.CORR_ID 
       AND LO.LOAN_ID = :NEW.loanid;

    :NEW.fieldid := l_new_fieldid;

END;
```

But this is an inferior solution. Triggers obscure what you are trying to really do and are hard to debug when there is a problem. The better solution is to correct your `INSERT` statement with what you're trying to really do.

Comment: Thanks Its Working .